# Column Validation for Two Different Columns in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a formula so that if my project

`[STATUS] = "4 - Closed"`

the user must also enter in a closed date in the `[CLOSED DATE]` field before they can save and exit the project. Every time I try, however, I either get an error, or it is requiring a date for All statuses.

Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: please add the Formulas you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=OR(AND([STATUS]="4-Closed";[CLOSED DATE]<>"");AND([STATUS]<>"4-Closed";[CLOSED DATE]=""))
```